# The `snapd` package fails to upgrade inside of Ubuntu 20.04 LXD container

Tags: snap, lxd

I'm launching Ubuntu 20.04 via LXD but, when I enter the container to use it, it fails to run:

```
apt update
apt full-upgrade
```

It stops on `Setting up snapd (2.47.1+20.04) ...` Error:

```
Setting up snapd (2.47.1+20.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

Logs:

```
Nov  1 14:04:01 cosstor-1 snapd[18306]: handlers.go:704: expected snap "snapd" revision 9607 to be mounted but is not
Nov  1 14:04:11 cosstor-1 snapd[18306]: taskrunner.go:271: [change 5 "Mount snap \"snapd\" (9607)" task] failed: cannot proceed, expected snap "snapd" revision 9607 to be mounted but is not
Nov  1 14:04:11 cosstor-1 snapd[18306]: handlers.go:495: Reported install problem for "snapd" as already-reported
```

Any idea about what to do?

I'm trying to remove (since I don't need it there) the `snapd` package with `apt purge snapd -y` as a first step when inside of Ubuntu 20.04 container but it also fails, error:

```
Removing snap core18 and revision 1885
rm: cannot remove '/snap/core18/1885': Device or resource busy
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 installed snapd package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What to do?  :-P

Is there an Ubuntu image from `https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases` (protocol: `simplestreams`) that doesn't come with "snapd" by default? Or maybe from another source?

EDIT 1: Found a workaround! `apt-mark hold snapd`...

EDIT 2: I have other LXD hosts where apparently the same Ubunt 20.04 container image works without problems, I just checked it and the `snapd` package is updated there! Everything is is Ubuntu 20.04, fully upgraded (bare-metal, containers, QEMU VMs)...

EDIT 3: People facing similar problems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1878674

I'm very close to dump Ubuntu and get back to Debian!  :-@

Thanks,
Thiago

Answer (score 0):

Use instead *the Ubuntu minimal LXD images.*

To do so, add the appropriate *remote* for the Ubuntu minimal LXD images:

```
lxc remote add --protocol simplestreams ubuntu-minimal https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/
```

To view the available images, run

```
$ lxc image list ubuntu-minimal:            # all container images, from 16.04 to 20.10.
$ lxc image list ubuntu-minimal:20.04   # view just the Ubuntu 20.04 container images.
$ lxc image list ubuntu-minimal:focal    # ditto.
$ lxc image info ubuntu-minimal:20.04   # get full info about the container image.
```

Read more at https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/ubuntu-20-04-images-are-available/7556 and https://blog.simos.info/a-closer-look-at-minimal-ubuntu-for-lxd/